# Java Delete files older than N days with Path, Filename and N days as variable

Tags: java

I would like some Java code to Delete files older than N days. I have seen a lot of example and codes here but not exactly what i need. I would like to be able to set the Path, Filename and the days( it can be 4 or 7 or 14 days) as variable because its will not always be the same.
Here is my attempt, but it doesn't work quite right.
Is there a simple way to solve this?

```
import java.io.File;
public class DeleteScript{
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(args.length);
    if(args.length != 3)
    {
    System.out.println("Bitte Pfad Zum Durschsuchen, Dateiname und Datei maximales Alter eingeben");
            System.exit(0);         
        } 
        String Path=args[0];     
        String FileName=args[1];
        String FileExtension=args[2];
        long Days= 7;
        if(args[0] == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Please Path and Filename!");
            System.exit(0);     
        }
        if(args[1] == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Bitte Dateiname eingeben!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(args[2] == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Bitte Datei maximales Alter eingeben!");
            System.exit(0);
        } 
        File folder = new File(Path);

        if (folder.exists()) {

            File[] listFiles = folder.listFiles();

            long eligibleForDeletion = System.currentTimeMillis() -
                (Days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            for (File listFile: listFiles) {

                if (listFile.getName().startsWith(Filename) && listFile.getName().endsWith(FileExtension) &&
                    listFile.lastModified() < eligibleForDeletion) {

                    if (!listFile.delete()) {

                        System.out.println("Error.. -:)");

                    }
                }
            }
        } 
}
```

}

Comment: *but it doesn't work quite right*   What isn't working? Do you get an error? Not the right output?

Comment: I am not getting the output. It just check the args.length and nothing else.

Comment: Also, please, please ident your code correctly and consitently. It increases the likelyhood of someone actually help you. In some places the { is in the same line, in some other, it is in the next line.

Comment: It just prints the length of the arguments. In my case just "3". Please I'm just new in Java. I tried to understand and reproduce some examples i have seen here to solve the task. Thkx in advance

Comment: Your code only prints if delete returns false. Maybe it returned true or maybe none of the files met the condition. You can sprinkle your code with System.out.println() statements to see where the code reached and so on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code to get you started. This code uses `Files.list` to get a `List<Path>` or the `Path` to each file in a folder. It then goes through the list of `Path` and determines if the file should be marked for deletion based on how the file name start, the extension of the file, and the date the file was created.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FileDeletion
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            // path of folder to check
            String extension = "txt";
            String startWith = "test";
            LocalDate beforeDate = LocalDate.parse("2018-06-05");

            String path = "C:/Users/userName/Desktop/test_folder";
            List<Path> paths = Files.list(Paths.get(path)).collect(Collectors.toList());

            for (Path entry : paths) {
                System.out.println("Entry: " + entry);
                BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(entry, BasicFileAttributes.class);
                System.out.println("\tCreation Time/UTC Time: " + attributes.creationTime());
                Instant instant = Instant.parse(attributes.lastModifiedTime().toString());
                LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC.getId()));
                System.out.println("\tLocal Date: " + ldt.toLocalDate());
                System.out.println("\tBefore Date: " + beforeDate);
                if (entry.getFileName().toString().startsWith(startWith) && entry.getFileName().toString().endsWith(extension) && ldt.toLocalDate().isBefore(beforeDate)) {
                    System.out.println("\tMarked for deletion: Yes");                      
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("\tMarked for deletion: No");
                }

                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileDeletion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I used your example to solve the problem. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ugly and does not follow the Java variable naming convention (Lower camel case).
You should change the variable names from Path or FileName to path and fileName.
Also you declare String **FileName**=args[1]; but in the if clause you use:
listFile.getName().startsWith(**Filename**).

The code functions ok for files modified more than 7 days ago.
I would also suggest to change
listFile.getName().startsWith(Filename) && listFile.getName().endsWith(FileExtension)
to
listFile.getName().equals(fileName + "." + fileExtension).